# On (Epi-Mono)-factorization structures

Tags: category-theory

Does there exists an example of a category that comes equipped with an $(Epi,Mono)$-factorization structure and such that epimorphisms are not split?

The choice of the factorization structure is too restrictive. So far, I think to the category of sets and functions, where any epimorphism is split. I hope that an $(Epi,Mono)$-category whose epimorphisms are split is not isomorphic to the category of sets, otherwise the assumptions I'm considering are very restrictive and useless.

Comment: Do you mean a category where (Epi, Mono) is a factorization system, but it is false that every epimorphism split? There is plenty: in the category of abelian groups, the quotient $\mathbb Z \to C_n$ can't have a section. In the category of unital rings, $\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Q$ is an epimorphism, but it can't have a section (such a section would be an injective ring homomorphism $\mathbb Q \to \mathbb Z$, there aren't any).

Comment: Yeah, thank you! For me $(Epi,Mono)$ is a factorization system (according to Adamek's terminology the category I'm considering is an $(Epi,Mono)$-category).

Comment: @fosco On the contrary, is there any (Epi,Mono)-category whose epimorphism are split and which is not isomorphic to the category of sets?

Comment: @TheWanderer The category with one object and only the identity arrow? You'll probably want something to exclude trivial examples like this. So better: the category of finite sets?

Comment: Something more complex?

Comment: @TheWanderer Any topos satisfying the external axiom of choice (see also https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/axiom+of+choice)?

Comment: On the same vein, another question is, can you take a category where epis do not split and embed it in one where they do? [more refined: take a category $C$ with a proper factorization system $(E,M)$; can you construct $C\hookrightarrow C^{sE}$ where in the codomain you added a section for each $e\in E$?] I thought about this question in this very moment, so it might be a very stupid one!

Comment: Most elementary topoi are examples